# Linux API: is it possible to specify `O_SYNC` option for a single `write` syscall

Tags: linux, asynchronous, io, system-calls, fsync

Such flags as `O_DIRECT`, `O_SYNC`, `O_DSYNC` can be used to specify synchronous / asynchronous IO at the time when descriptor is created (`create` syscall). But is it possible to use this flags for distinct `write` (or similar) syscalls in order to make some of them synchronous?

Comment: Can't you just do what the manual says `O_SYNC` effectively does: `i.e., as though each write(2) was followed by a call to fsync(2)`

Comment: Can you not just call `fsync` or `fdatasync` on the descriptor after the `write` call?

Comment: Thanks @kaylum, @alaniwi , to clarify my question, I'm debuggind a service with high IOPS consumption. It's configured to use async writes only, but according to statistics, it looks like it's use all disk bandwidth just like if it wrote synchronously. So I'm trying to use `strace` to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to use this flags for distinct write (or similar) syscalls in order to make some of them synchronous?

No, `O_SYNC` is meaningful only for the purposes it is documented for: `open()` and related syscalls.  Data transfer system calls such as `write()` do not accept flags.  Whether writes are synchronous is a property of the open file description, not of individual data transfer operations.

You can, however, follow up individual `write()` calls with `fsync()` calls on the same file descriptor to ensure that the data are dispatched to the physical device.

Alternatively, you can use `fcntl()` to modify the file's flags after opening it.  You would

1. read and store the current flags

   ```
   int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
   ```
2. set new flags that include `O_SYNC`

   ```
   int result = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_SYNC);
   ```
3. perform the `write`
4. restore the original flags

   ```
   result = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
   ```

(Note: function call results need to be checked for error conditions.  Such checks are omitted from the above summary for clarity.)

Unless you absolutely need the `write` call itself to be synchronous, however, it is much easier to leave the flags alone and just call `fsync()` where needed.  That's what it's for, after all.

Comment: If there is a difference between the effects of using O_SYNC (when opening the file) or using fsync() (wafter ich write to the file)?

Comment: @Silicomancer, if you specify `O_SYNC` when opening the file, then the system behaves approximately as if every write to the file is followed by an `fsync()` for the file.  It cannot be *exactly* the same because separating the syncing from the writing affords the opportunity for one to succeed despite the other failing.